# Android get camera torch mode

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

Android's `CameraManager` has only a function `setTorchMode(String cameraId, boolean enabled)` to enable or disable the flashlight. However, in order to toggle it, I need to know the current state. Is there a way to get it? Listener is not an option since other apps can turn it on or off.

Answer (score 1):

In official documentation, I haven't found the possibility to get the current state of the Torch via Android API.

Here is an idea, how you can solve that problem:

1. Create a Service, which will start on device boot
2. Register [Camera.TorchCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.TorchCallback.html) in this Service
3. Keep Torch state in a
   Service and pass it somewhere whenever you need to (e.g. via Event Bus or `BroadcastReceiver`). You can also keep this state in class deriving from `Application` class from Android SDK.

It's not a perfect answer to your question, but maybe you'll find it helpful.